# Run multiple Selenium Test Projects across Azure DevOps

Tags: selenium, azure-devops, automated-tests, azure-pipelines

We have a main CRM application, that used to be housed externally but has been brought in-house. We have all our stand-alone websites/apps/etc that update/read from this main application. Each of those individual projects have their own selenium tests associated with them. What I assume those projects due, is drum up the resources, builds the tests, and runs against those existing websites, and gets rid of the resources, because no longer needed.

It seems like we should be able to reference those build pipelines from one project into another. Is there a way to do this? Seems like it would be easier to manage this way.

From what I have read, copy the test dll's into the main crm project to run. Is that what is needed to be done? The test piece on the CRM application will find all those test dlls? And then all the reporting are under the main crm sometimes and sometimes under the stand alone projects in other times? I much rather would like the test results to be associated with the repos/projects associated with the functional area.

Comment: Not totally get your point. Do you meant that create a test project/case, then run this test case/project against all the applications? Whatever, please check if this blog helps : [Automating Selenium Tests in Azure Pipelines](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/selenium/), it uses the Deployment Group to test in different machines.

Comment: I think you got my point and pointed me in the right direction. Adding that deployment group, I am now able to see all projects included in that deployment group under our main CRM, and feel that I should be able to kick off each build pipeline that has my tests in them. If you want to move your comment to answer, I will definitely give you the checkmark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the solution is that you can add a deployment group, with the Deployment Group you could test the applications in different machines.

In your scenario, you could see all projects included in that deployment group under your main CRM, then you could kick off each build pipeline has your tests in them.

Please refer to [Automating Selenium Tests in Azure Pipelines](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/selenium/) for details